# Simple game on GAE using Python, where should the logic be?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I have recently started to learn Python and have read the book Head first with python as well as done the tutorial on [Python runtime environment GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/). So far so good.

Now I want to make a small project using Python just to get a bit more experience while doing something meaningful. I picked making a small card game for a browser that will be hosted on GAE.

I have a main.py that displays the index.html file that greets the user and a game.html file that is loaded when the user clicks play on the homepage. I also have a deck.py and card.py which represents the deck and card. For now these are very vague with only one value in the card class and 4 cards in a list in the deck.

I use jinja2 to serve the html templates and webapp2 as my web framework.

In the game.html I want to display everything that has to do with the game. Showing the initial setup of the game, dealing more cards, dealing with button presses, updating which cards are in play, and so on.

I have tried creating the a deck object in the main.py and then passing it to the html through jinja in hopes that I could store it somehow on the page but that does not seem to work.

The question is, where do I make the game logic happen?
Am I forced to use javascript to code my game and the logic?

Thanks for any input..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tough question. Typically, you would do all the changes to your UI in Javascript. But how much game logic you want to do in python is up to you, but you still need to redraw the screen, and you need a fast way to send requests back and forth between javascript and your server, which is the python side. Some games do a lot of intense server side work, like clash of clans. But typically the logic is in the client, either in the browser in javascript or flash, or on a mobile device, and the server is just saving information. It's always a trade off between speed, convenience, and how much you want to track on the server - you would do that for people who want to keep track of what they are doing on multiple devices, for instance.

Comment: I am looking to maximize the Python code usage. I do not really care about any other thing as long as it works and is playable.
So I am thinking that I can send which button is pressed to the server side, do the logic in Python (on the server), and then send back to the client what needs to be changed. The way I think of it would not be very elegant since I would send the whole webpage, with slightly different variables, each time something happens in the game. What do you think?

Comment: Depends on the complexity, and how often you need to refresh your page. Seconds per call may nor may not work. Typically, if you're going to do it this way, you'd want to create the web page as a 'single page' app, and just replace the elements that need replacing, not refresh the entire page. That would involved jquery probably, and a framework like backbone or angular.

Answer (score -1):

For a simple game, you should first write it as a standalone Python program using `input()` and `print()` statements.  Then, replace the input with HTTP GET requests from the client, and the output with HTML.  While this is overkill (you completely rewrite the page with every request), it is good enough to get you started.  Later on, you can optimize the page.

The advantage of this approach is that you can test the game logic without worrying about the browser, GAE, frameworks, etc.  It also makes it easier to debug when things break.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am going to do :)  I just can't start working on the game yet and decided to try to see how I would go about uploading it. Btw, I will be using images for the cards. But you are right. A simple print out will be the best way to start it once I have the game logic in python running.

Comment: If you like this answer, please mark it as "Accepted" (and optionally give it an upvote by clicking on the up-arrow).  Thanks!